# Choosing matrix elements (matrix language)

Tags: spss

I would like to choose specific elements of matrix or vector, lets say greater then 0. One option is to loop thru every element of my matrix / vector, but I wonder if there is a better way to achieve this (like in R, with which condition). My code looks like this:

```
matrix.
compute A={1,2,5,6,1,6,0,4,0,3,6,0,2,-3}.
compute b=0.

loop #i=1 to ncol(A).
    do if ( A(1,#i) >0 ).
        compute b={b,a(1,#i)}.
    end if.
end loop.

compute b=b(1,2:ncol(b)).
print b.

end matrix.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the indices you want, you can simply supply those in a seperate subset vector.

```
matrix.
compute A={1,2,5,6,1,6,0,4,0,3,6,0,2,-3}.
compute take = {1,2,4}.
print A(take).
end matrix.
```

Which produces `1  2  6` on the print statement. Now, grabbing the indices is slightly annoying. One way is to use `GRADE` on the negation of meeting condition, which provides an ordering to grab the indices you want. Then only select the total number of indices that you know meet the condition.

```
matrix.
compute A={1,2,5,6,1,6,0,4,0,3,6,0,2,-3}.

*make sequential index and vector with selection.
compute take = {1:NCOL(A)}.
compute sel = A > 0.

*reording the indices so the selected columns are first.
compute take(GRADE(-1*sel)) = take.

*only taking the indices that meet the selection.
compute take = take(1:RSUM(sel)).

*results.
print A.
print A(take).
end matrix.
```

This can be rolled up into a macro to make this alittle easier. Here is an example that would work here.

```
DEFINE !SelCol (Data = !TOKENS(1)
               /Condition = !TOKENS(1) 
               /Result = !TOKENS(1) )
COMPUTE XKeepX = !UNQUOTE(!Condition).
COMPUTE XIndX = {1:NCOL(!Data)}.
COMPUTE XIndX(GRADE(XKeepX*-1)) = XIndX.
COMPUTE XIndX = XIndX(1:RSUM(XKeepX)).
COMPUTE !Result = !Data(1:NROW(!Data),XIndX).
RELEASE XKeepX.
RELEASE XIndX.
!ENDDEFINE.

MATRIX.
COMPUTE A={1,2,5,6,1,6,0,4,0,3,6,0,2,-3}.
!SelCol Data=A Condition='A>0' Result=ASel.
PRINT ASel.
END MATRIX.
```

This approach is readily adaptable to selecting specific rows of a matrix as well.

```
DEFINE !SelRow (Data = !TOKENS(1)
               /Condition = !TOKENS(1)
               /Result = !TOKENS(1) )
COMPUTE XKeepX = !UNQUOTE(!Condition).
COMPUTE XIndX = {1:NROW(!Data)}.
COMPUTE XIndX(GRADE(XKeepX*-1)) = XIndX.
COMPUTE XIndX = XIndX(1:CSUM(XKeepX)).
COMPUTE !Result = !Data(XIndX,1:NCOL(!Data)).
RELEASE XKeepX.
RELEASE XIndX.
!ENDDEFINE.
```

This should be pretty fast. Most of the time will be spent on the conditional statement and extracting the data. Ranking the index should be pretty trivial even for a really large number of rows or columns.